# How to make vim shell command wait for keypress?

Tags: command-line, external-command

I have assigned the macro `!clear && gcc % && ./a.out` to the key 'r'.

So when I press '@r', I expect vim to:

1. Clear the shell
2. compile the current C file
3. run the output

The problem is that it does all three but does not wait at the output screen where it shows "Press ENTER or type command to continue" and comes back to command mode.

Comment: Please show the exact map command you are using. EDIT: I just saw you use `@r` so that is a macro and not a map. You have to end the recording of the macro before you press enter at the "hit enter" prompt otherwise that will be part of the macro. (press `q` before `enter`).

Comment: Indeed, it is a macro. 
Yes, I quit recording before hitting enter, so that isn't the problem. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: For me this works in vim 8.1.22: `@r!clear && seq 200<CR>q` (I use `seq` because I don't have your c program and `<CR>` is the return key here). The I can later type `@r` and it executes `seq` again and stops at the hit enter prompt. Did you `set more`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't currently have access to the system.
I am fairly new to vim so I did not know of the `set more` command. Will try and confirm. 
Thanks!

Comment: @Apoorve Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SimonPuente I added (what works for me) as an answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @Apoorve it works, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what was the problem then, but on Vim 8.1.1600 (on macOS Catalina), the following works for me now.

Example C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main() {
  printf("%d", 5);
  return 0;
}
```

Vim sequence to record the macro-

1. Ensure you are in normal mode
2. Press `qg` to start recording the macro for the key `g`
3. Press `:w` and then press `enter`
4. Press `:!clear && gcc % && ./a.out` (% refers to the current filename)
5. Press `q` to stop recording

It is important that at the time of recording the macro, you don't press any key between steps 4 and 5, because this example C does not require any input.

To execute the macro, press `@g`